# selenium×pythonを使い商品登録をしたいと思っています

Tags: python, selenium

seleniumIDEを使いコードを取得しました。

画像の登録など最初の段階ではうまくいっていたのですが、エラーが出て思うように動かなくなりました。

エラー部分を検索したのですが、いまいち原因が特定できずに困っています。

ご教授いただければ幸いです。よろしくお願いいたします。

**ソースコード**

```
># -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoAlertPresentException
import unittest, time, re

class UntitledTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(30)
        self.base_url = "https://www.katalon.com/"
        self.verificationErrors = []
        self.accept_next_alert = True

    def test_untitled_test_case(self):
        driver = self.driver

    def is_element_present(self, how, what):
        try: self.driver.find_element(by=how, value=what)
        except NoSuchElementException as e: return False
        return True

    def is_alert_present(self):
        try: self.driver.switch_to_alert()
        except NoAlertPresentException as e: return False
        return True

    def close_alert_and_get_its_text(self):
        try:
            alert = self.driver.switch_to_alert()
            alert_text = alert.text
            if self.accept_next_alert:
                alert.accept()
            else:
                alert.dismiss()
            return alert_text
        finally: self.accept_next_alert = True

    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.quit()
        self.assertEqual([], self.verificationErrors)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

**エラー内容**

```
>E
======================================================================
ERROR: test_untitled_test_case (__main__.UntitledTestCase)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/shogo/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 76, in start
    stdin=PIPE)
  File "/Users/shogo/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 709, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/Users/shogo/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 1344, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'geckodriver': 'geckodriver'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/shogo/Desktop/\u6cb3\u91ce\u662d\u543e/flil.py", line 12, in setUp
    self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
  File "/Users/shogo/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 152, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/Users/shogo/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 83, in start
    os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH. 


----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.014s

FAILED (errors=1)
[Finished in 0.381s]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RustyNail(Twitter: @oh_rusty_nail) です。

まず、私の環境でも上記のコードで同様のエラーが出ることを確認しました。
そして、以下の対応で解消できました。
1. https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases から最新のgeckodriverを入手
2. zipファイルの解凍してディレクトリへコピー

```
$ tar -zxvf ./geckodriver-v0.20.0-macos.tar.gz
$ sudo cp ./geckodriver /usr/local/bin
```

#### 実行結果

```
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 5.157s

OK
```

---

日本SeleniumユーザーコミュニティのSlackルームを作っています。
Slackの方がレスポンス早いかもしれないので紹介させていただきます。
入室方法なども以下に書いていますので、よろしければご参加ください。
https://selenium-danwakai.connpass.com/

半年に一度まとまって集まる会を設けていますが、随時質問なども大歓迎です。
最近の活動記録です。
https://qiita.com/oh_rusty_nail/items/a7396a3b1f086e06ac1f

Comment: Masayuki様、ご回答ありがとうございます。無事実行することができました。コミュニティの方ぜひ参加させていただきたく思います。この度は誠にありがとうございました。